# Finding a vertex cover for a graph in java

Tags: java, graph

So I have some code which finds items in an array which are greater than itself in respect to its position. So for example if the list was:

[1,3,2]

2 and 3 would need to be swapped, to be ordered so they would be added to the adjacency list.

However, for slightly larger problems I want to be able to find the vertex cover of the graph such that of a graph is a set of vertices such that each edge of the graph is incident to at least one vertex of the set

Want I'm looking for is something like this for example [4,2,3,1]:[image]

```
    public class VertexCover{

        /**
         * @param args the command line arguments
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO code application logic here
            int[] row = {4, 2, 1, 5};
            Vertex[] adjLists = new Vertex[row.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < adjLists.length; i++) {
                adjLists[i] = new Vertex(row[i], null);
            }

            int max = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                    if (adjLists[i].value > adjLists[j].value && i < j) {
                        adjLists[i].adjList = new Neighbour(j, adjLists[i].adjList);
                        adjLists[j].adjList = new Neighbour(i, adjLists[j].adjList);
                    }
                }
            }



            for (int i = 0; i < adjLists.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(adjLists[i].value);
                for (Neighbour neighbour = adjLists[i].adjList; neighbour != null; neighbour = neighbour.next) {
                    System.out.print("---->" + adjLists[neighbour.vertexNum].value);
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }



        }
    }

    class Vertex {

        int value;
        Neighbour adjList;

        Vertex(int value, Neighbour neighbours) {
            this.value = value;
            this.adjList = neighbours;
        }
    }

    class Neighbour {

        int vertexNum;
        public Neighbour next;

        public Neighbour(int vnum, Neighbour next) {
            this.vertexNum = vnum;
            this.next = next;
        }
    }
```

I can't find anything on this, apart from its np complete.

Comment: You haven't said anything about where this graph is coming from.

Comment: I've created it in the code, it creates an edge between two vertices when paired nodes are unordered @user2357112